# Implement Reservation System

Tags: java, mysql, performance, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing a spring boot MVC REST API for mobile application ,The system is a patient booking in the clinic, I am looking for the best solution to the problem of displaying the available times of the doctor.

problem definition : the system shall allow the user to choose ,clinic , doctor and the specific date(year/month/day) from the calendar and the system shall show the available times for the chooses date , the appointment duration is 30 min and from 7 am to 6 pm .

more clarification : 
The system is consist of many clinics and doctors belong to these clinics , Each doctor has fixed hours for which the user can book. These hours are divided into the dates of each half-hour appointment. Users can not book at the same doctor at the same time .

example : 
Patient Joey booked an appointment at Doctor x , at 21-may-2018 3:30 ,
another patient jack has opened the application to book an appointment he chooses doctor x and he chooses the same date as joey (21-may-2018) the system shall show times available from 7 am to 6 pm (7 :00 , 7:30 , 8:00 , 8:30 ......)exclude 3:30 .

Solutions tried : 
1) make a job in the data base that fill the available times every year and mark the time with flag.
2) when the client ask for the available times the system iterate over the all appointments for the doctor and find these times.
3) make a static list with times and dates and when the user ask for the available times iterate over the appointments and remove the times belong to an appointment from the list . 
4) make a database calendar.
5) let the user of the admin page fill the times manually from the admin page. 
i tried all these possible solutions but i did not find them very efficient i am looking for a better solution .

code sample : 
 controller section:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET , value = "/availabletimes")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseUtil> getAvailableTimes(@RequestParam String date){

    try {
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseUtil> (new ResponseUtil(200, Constants.SUCCESS_STATUS, "Cancelled", service.getAvailableTimes(date)),HttpStatus.OK);
    }catch (BackendException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseUtil> (new ResponseUtil(403, Constants.FAILED_STATUS, e.getMessage(), null),HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

}
```

Service implementation :

```
@Override
public List<String> getAvailableTimes(String date) {
    List<String> availableTimes = findAvailableTimes(date);

    if(availableTimes == null || availableTimes.isEmpty())
        throw new BackendException("No times available for the given date");

    return availableTimes;
}

private List<String> findAvailableTimes(String date){

    //TODO write the logic for findding the available times 
    return null;
}
```

Repository :

```
 public interface AppointmentRepo extends IRepository<Appointment, Long> {

List<Appointment> findByCustomer(Customer customer);

     }
```

entity :

```
@Entity
public class Appointment extends BaseEntity {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Date appoitmentDate;

// Relations
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Doctor doctor;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Clinic clinic;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Customer customer;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Follower follower;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private AppointmentStatus appointmentStatus;
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Report report;

// Setters and Getters
public Doctor getDoctor() {
    return doctor;
}

public void setDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
    this.doctor = doctor;
}

public Clinic getClinic() {
    return clinic;
}

public void setClinic(Clinic clinic) {
    this.clinic = clinic;
}

public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public Follower getFollower() {
    return follower;
}

public void setFollower(Follower follower) {
    this.follower = follower;
}

public Date getAppoitmentDate() {
    return appoitmentDate;
}

public void setAppoitmentDate(Date appoitmentDate) {
    this.appoitmentDate = appoitmentDate;
}

public AppointmentStatus getAppointmentStatus() {
    return appointmentStatus;
}

public void setAppointmentStatus(AppointmentStatus appointmentStatus) {
    this.appointmentStatus = appointmentStatus;
}

public Report getReport() {
    return report;
}

public void setReport(Report report) {
    this.report = report;
}

}
```

Comment: Sorry, this question is way too broad.

Comment: I can't make sense of any of the five solutions listed. Moreover, efficient in what sense? You need a single huge table, a few indexes and a single SQL query, so it must be fast unless you ran it with terabytes of data.

Comment: `if(availableTimes == null || availableTimes.isEmpty())
        throw new BackendException("No times available for the given date");` This feels wrong. 1. Never let your method return `null` needlessly. 2. An empty list is just that: an empty list. It's no error.

Answer (score 1):

I have an open source scheduling utility library (for Android) that works with hours of business and scheduling items. It has a facility to check for double bookings but as of yet it does not have a direct mechanism for returning appointment slots but I will be adding this as a priority. You can use an array of this library for different clinics. You can get slots indirectly by using the mechanism in the library for getting the next available slot at or after a given time and looping through each appointment. The landing page is here: https://bitbucket.org/warwick/schedule_utils_demo/src/master/ it also comes with a demo  app along with its' source code. You can also download the demo app from the Google Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.WarwickWestonWright.ScheduleUtilsDemo
Though it is an Android library it is extremely easy to turn it into a standard Java library as I built it with this in mind. I'll update this post when I've added the mechanism for getting a list of available slots.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a programming question, but a datadesign question.

Make a table(entity) `ClinicDoctorSchedule` with primary key `clinic_id, doctor_id`, a `timedate` and a foreign key to `patient_id` and a `state` field. The state field can have the following values : open, reserved, used, no show. Default is open

Fill this table with the schedules (A Schedule describes in which clinic, which doctor has time available) for the next two months.

This is a lot of work, but once you have it, you can update the table on a weekly basis. (Make increments of a week) Though it is a lot work initially, it is also a flexible solution since a change in schedule is easy to apply

The patient select a `weeknumber` and the system returns form the `ClinicDoctorSchedule` all `timedates` where `clinic_id` = selected clinic en  `doctor_id` = selected doctor and `timedate` is between `firstweekdayhour` AND `lastweekdayhour` and `state` = open.

When the patient selects a `datetime` two things happen:

1. The foreign key value is  filled with `patient_id`
2. The state` goes from open to reserved.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: thanks , but what do you think about make a table called time and get those times to a list , then obtain the  available times by deleting the times that matches any appointment time.

Comment: @MahmoodMousa But why? With the single table keyed by `(clinic, doctor, timedate)`  and linking to `patient` (or NULL when still available), you get everything you need using a single SQL query, so why would you use two? As probably most of the slots gets filled by a patient, you won't store useless data, so it sounds perfect to me. Just add indexes for common searches. All you need is a job generating new slots as time passes, based on other tables (or import files), where an administrator enters the doctors' plans.